# работа со строкой через указатель

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

есть строка, я хочу сделать на нее указатель и непосредственно через указатель изменить первый элемент:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string a = "abcdefg";
  string* b = &a;
  cout << a << endl;
  b[0] = "b";
  cout << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

но при компиляции получаю ответ

```
 abcdefg
 b
```

если же я попытаюсь `b[1] = "c";` то ответ будет:

```
abcdefg
abcdefg
```

Comment: Ну, вам уже хорошо рассказали. Мне только интересно, вы вот тут не заметили у себя несообразности - пытаетесь присвоить символу (ну, как вы полагали) **строку**: `b[0] = "b"`. Ну, а непосредственно через указатель то, что вы хотели, можно записать и, например, так: `b->operator[](0) = 'b';` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы запутались с использованием оператора `[]`:

```
string* b = &a;
// ...
b[0] = "b";
```

Строка `b[0]` эквивалентна `*(b + 0)`, что в свою очередь эквивалентно `*b`. Таким образом, вы просто перезаписали всю строку `a`, поскольку `b` указывает на нее.

```
b[1] = "c";
```

А вот так делать **категорически нельзя**. Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к памяти по адресу, который вам может не принадлежать, что приводит к неопределенному поведению программы (undefined behavior).

Для того, чтобы изменить конкретный символ в строке через указатель на нее, необходимо сначала разыменовать указатель, и только уже после этого менять сам элемент:

```
(*b)[1] = 'с';
```

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "abcdef";
    std::string* b = &a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    (*b)[1] = 'c';
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```